# How to set Nuxt dynamic route category page and content page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I use NUXT to build my project.

This is my file structure now:

```
pages/
--| work/
-----| index.vue
-----| _projectName.vue
```

I want to do this:

```
A: /work = all work list    
B: /work/_categoryName(like is "/work/web-design" = category "web desing" work list)
C: /work/_categoryName?type=A(like is "/work/web-design?type=A" = category "web desing" and type A work list)

D: /work/_projectName(like is "/work/XXXproject") = project content
```

A, B, C use the same page.
D use different page and different layout.

How can I do?

---

update:

If the way that I want to do above is impossible, or try another way:

```
A: /work = all work list    
B: /work/_categoryName
C: /work/_categoryName?type=A

D: /work/content/_projectName
```

A, B, C use the same page
How can I do? Layouts? Components? Mixin?

Comment: How to differentiate category vs project? for route /work/web-design, is it possible that `web-design` is a project name AND category name?

Comment: `web-design` is example. The category is dynamic route from database. Is it possible to work 2 dynamic route?

Answer (score 0):

I think this structure makes what you want

```
pages/
--| work/
-----| index.vue
-----| _projectName.vue
-----| web-design.vue   --> and use route parameter to accessing type
```

And in _projectName.vue set the layout like this example

_projectName.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'the-layout'
```

.....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `/work` and `/web-design` are the same content. They're just different category, and the category is dynamic data. I think this way isn't great for my project.